# Sphinx 2x , Adding WHERE clause having used sql_field_string

Tags: php, sphinx, cakephp-2.3

I am building an application which requires search.

I am using sphinx 2.0x and it has been giving me results.

Now, I want to filter through as we do using `where` in MySQL example, `select * from properties where`type`= 'house'` I am trying to add a filter on Sphinx search.

I am using https://github.com/CakeNKeyboard/Sphinx-CakePHP and the API that I have, (just checked) requires filter's second argument to be an array and assert requires to know if that is a number. I do not like to touch the api file nor behaviour file.

Checked this : [Sphinx 2.0.2 Filtering sql_attr_string Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718014/sphinx-2-0-2-filtering-sql-attr-string-attributes) made sense!

But where do I add WHERE MATCH ??? I am using behaviour for this and api file asserts if value is number but I want to check on string.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH(..) is the 'full-text' query itself.

So in the API, its the ->Query call.

SphinxQL also makes extended match mode as the default, so to use the @ syntax in the API, you also need to explicitly request SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED

Comment: Thanks for helping... But, sorry, it is bit difficult to understand what you are helping me with, can you please re-phrase it? `so to use the @ syntax in the API, you also need to explicitly request SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED` ??

Comment: I know that stuff. Saw it, my question is about implementation, please be kind to share if we know what my question is.

Comment: Well looking in the source, the 'query' call, is done using the 'search' string.         $result = $this->runtime[$model->alias]['sphinx']->query($query['search'], $indexes);
 So uoi need to edit the 'search' to include the required values

Comment: So rather than searching say "furry dice" the search would become "furry dice @type house"

Comment: Thanks @barryhunter tried that but it didn't work. I concatenated my search string with ` @type house` (with a space in the beginning), it didn't work. If you are CakePHP guy do u want me to show you my code? I can edit the question, if you like?

Comment: is 'type' actully a `field` in your index?

Comment: yes, it is.. I renamed the column, indexer --all --rotate , search again with a @newcolumnname , no change. Reverted. Saves a trouble!

Comment: I hope it doesn't have to do with my engine? I am using InnoDB - under MySQL.

Comment: I am using Sphinx example sphinx.conf but the Match is not working always giving empty result, can anyone tell will be the reason ?