# Searching on multiple fulltext fields with Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am trying to use sphinxsearch to search on multiple fields, in essence to get around the restriction on numeric IDs used in attributes for search filtering (the database uses a lot of alphanumeric uniqIDs as ids instead).

Here's the main search used in the Sphinx config:

```
sql_query               = \
        SELECT text_page.id, text_page.document_id, documents.startdate, documents.enddate, documents.long_title, documents.volume,text_page.images_page_id, text_page.text, \
        series.name, series.id AS series_id, series.white_label_id AS white_label_id, \
        documents.date_created\
        FROM text_page \
        INNER JOIN documents ON text_page.document_id = documents.id \
        INNER JOIN series ON documents.series_id = series.id
```

text_page.text is the main fulltext field.

I have added this line to the config to try to get this row fulltext indexed as well:

```
sql_field_string = white_label_id
```

I then tried to create a query narrowed by white_label_id by running the following query through the PHP Sphinx class.

```
"@text (search words) @white_label_id (some-uniq-id)"
```

As I understand it [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718014/sphinx-2-0-2-filtering-sql-attr-string-attributes/8725379#8725379), this should mean both @text and @white_label_id have to produce hits on the database row to return a result.

However the query produces no results ever, and no errors or warnings.

Any suggestion as to what is going wrong here? Is it because `white_label_id` and `text` fields are on different tables? Is there a solution that avoids restructuring the database to use numeric IDs?

### Edited:

As requested, here is a full config file.
**Note at present the code is still using the PHP Sphinx Class, rather than SphinxQL via mysqli.**

```
source src2
{

    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = username
    sql_pass                = password
    sql_db                  = databasename
    sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306 
    sql_query_pre           = SET NAMES utf8

    sql_query               = \
        SELECT text_page.id, text_page.document_id, documents.startdate, documents.enddate, documents.long_title, documents.volume,text_page.images_page_id, text_page.text, \
        series.name, series.id AS series_id, series.white_label_id AS white_label_id, \
        documents.date_created\
        FROM text_page \
        INNER JOIN documents ON text_page.document_id = documents.id \
        INNER JOIN series ON documents.series_id = series.id

    
    sql_attr_uint                   = startdate
    sql_attr_uint                   = enddate
    sql_attr_uint                   = volume

    sql_attr_timestamp      = date_created


    sql_attr_string     = long_title
    sql_attr_string     = name
    #sql_attr_string        = white_label_id #NB - does not work with nonnumeric ids
    sql_attr_string     = document_id
    sql_attr_string     = series_id

    sql_field_string = white_label_id  #currently appears to do nothing

    
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0 
}

source src2throttled : src2
{
    sql_ranged_throttle         = 100
}

index myindex11
{
    
    source          = src2
    path            = /var/data/mydata1
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = none
    min_word_len        = 1
    charset_type        = utf-8
    html_strip              = 0

}

index myindex1stemmed : myindex1
{
    path            = /var/data/mydata1stemmed
    morphology      = stem_en
    index_exact_words   = 1
}
```

Comment: You should provide a full minimal config that reproduces your problem (an actual `sql_query` can be replaced with some dummy one like `select 1 as id, 'a12' as white_label_id...`).

Comment: As you have white_label_id as an attribute, can reteive so test with `SELECT id,white_label_id FROM indexname WHERE MATCH('@text (search words)') ` to see if the white_label_id is present in the results. to see the document is really indexed.

Comment: @hank. With apologies for the delay, please see the configuration I've added.

Comment: @barryhunter I'm not using SphinxQL at the moment, so I can't do that without some reconfiguration, albeit I should probably move to that configuration asap.

Comment: @fred2 I've rewrited your sql_query the way I mentioned in my first comment, and I don't have any problems with queries like `@text text @white_label_id a123`. Try to check if your index has the data you're searching for like barryhunter said.

Comment: Well you have a `sql_field_string` so should be available as an attribute. Can use setSelect to create a query that returns the attribute, to see what get - for testing purposes. But even if not using SPhinxQL for application, its a useful way to run quick test queries, in using the `mysql` command line client. It helps you understand what going on. - also did you rebuild the index, after chaning config??

Comment: @Barryhunter if you want to word your comment as an answer I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: what was the actual problem. at the moment, we've been mostly trying to prompt you do more debugging. not bothered by the bounty as such.

Comment: @barryhunter. Yeah I'm actually struggling to find time to work through this properly, as I implemented a workaround in the short term. I also need to spend time getting SphinxQL working on my development machine, because at present trying to get it to work through the MySQL client isn't working, nor via PHP mysqli. Let me try to do more investigating and get back to you. Once SphinxQL works it will be easier to see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it turns out there's a much better solution to working around the 'numeric only' rule on Sphinx column ids.

The answer is to create a numeric hash of text-based uniq_id columns, which can then be used as `sql_attr_uint` to narrow searches.

For example, the SQL query in the original post becomes:

```
sql_query               = \
        SELECT text_page.id, text_page.document_id, documents.startdate, documents.enddate, documents.long_title, documents.volume,text_page.images_page_id, text_page.text, \
        series.name, series.id AS series_id, CRC32(series.white_label_id) AS white_label_id, \
        documents.date_created\
        FROM text_page \
        INNER JOIN documents ON (text_page.document_id = documents.id AND documents.is_active = 1) \
        INNER JOIN series ON documents.series_id = series.id
```